# How to create session in jquery to use in multiple forms

Tags: jquery

In `Form_1` I'm setting the session :

```
   <form action="form_2.php" >
   <input type="text" id="zipcode" maxlength="7" name="zipcode">
   </form>


<script>
   $("form").submit(function(){
      var zipcode = $('#zipcode').val();   
      $.session.set("zipcode","zipcode");
      alert($.session.get("zipcode"));// NOT WORKING :(   
   });

</script>
```

Meanwhile, the session is not used nor destroyed.

In `form_3` I'm getting the session but its not working :

```
 var zipcode=$.session.get('zipcode'); //NOT WORKING
```

Comment: open in both forms the browser developer tools with F12 and let us know what is in the sessionStorage via Tab Application -> Session Storage

Comment: i see no key and no value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
    // save data to sessionStorage
    sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

    // get data from sessionStorage
    var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

Referring to following link:
[Window.sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

This example works:

```
<form action="form_2.php" >
   <input type="text" id="zipcode" maxlength="7" name="zipcode">
</form>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
   $("form").submit(function(){
      var zipcode = $('#zipcode').val();   
      sessionStorage.setItem("zipcode", zipcode);
      alert(sessionStorage.getItem("zipcode"));
   });    
</script>
```

Comment: i used var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');  alert (data); its alert null

Comment: but the session is filled and visible in developer tools?

Comment: No I don’t see  In application session storage

Comment: Thanks for you @trura you made my day!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the handler function needs to prevent the default form submission.

Assuming there is one form on the page:

```
$form = $("form")
$form.submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var zipcode = $('#zipcode').val();   
   $.session.set("zipcode", zipcode);
   $form.submit();
});
```

Comment: @DUMB_CODER did you debug? put `debugger;` statement to somewhere in JS your code, open devtools, refresh the page. With limited visibility to your code, it is hard to find out what you are asking for :)

Comment: Thanks for your time @cmertayak the above one is working needed to add some link :) all i needed was pass value into session and use it